# How do I find the offending code from new PySimpleGUI error popup

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Does any body know how can I find what line of code is the offending line from this Popup error message:

[image]

Comment: It don't tell you what the line number of the offending code, but it tell you that you use wrong layout in `sg.Tab([sg.Text(...),])`, maybe correct as `sg.Tab([[sg.Text(...),],])`

Comment: Thank you @JasonYang ! Well, I did fine the offending code by looking at the GUI and observing a missing text field. The error was a missing opening square bracket. Mind you, there are plenty of text fields in my GUI, quite a hay-stack, but I did find the needle...!

Answer (score 0):

Hi All PySimpleGUI users!

The key knowledge item here is the object *type*, e.g. sg.text in the above. Once you identify that, and since it is removed from the layout, you visually inspect all items of this type and see which one is missing. From there you can go to the bad layout.